# How to train watson on names entity or general string?

Tags: watson-assistant

I need to train watson assistant on the following utterance, what is the order status of Bob/Jane or some name.

I tried with @sys-person but it does not recognize all names.

I defined an intent like this 
what is order status of @name
and created entity @name as \b[A-Za-z0-9]\b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use for contextual entities. You can read up on those here:

1. [Contextual Entities with IBM Watson Assistant](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/contextual-entities-with-ibm-watson-assistant-f41b2e0ca82e)
2. All about entities: Contextual entities with Watson Assistanthttps://medium.com/ibm-watson/all-about-entities-contextual-entities-with-watson-assistant-part-2-7697d2b73db0)

The idea is that you don't need your bot to know all possible names in advance, but instead it can recognize a name based on the context within an intent.

To set this up, you'd go to your order status intent and add some training examples such as:

- what is the order status of Name
- what is the order status of Another Name
- what is the order status of Yet Another Name

(These examples can have any kind of name, whether fake or real.)

And then you'll annotate each of those to associate the name with the `@name` entity, by double-clicking on the name portion of the training examples (i.e. Name, Another Name, Yet Another Name) to bring up the entity selection UI and specifying your `@name` entity.

After Watson finishes training, you can test it in the "Try it out" window. Enter something like "what is the order status of Charles Flint" or "what is the order status of Thomas Watson" and you should see your `@name` entity matched. From there, you can access the name specified by the user with `@name.value`.

Comment: Thanks it works! but I have some non english names and auto correction is on. Its correcting those names, but if I switch it off, I loose the auto correction option for rest if utterances, which I feel is needed. I added name as regex till now

Comment: Is there a way to invoke an intent based on user text like "<? input.text ?>" == "done"

Comment: @JohnRuby do you mean invoke a dialog node? Sure, you could use `input.text == "done"` in the "If assistant recognizes" field, i.e. the node's condition. No need for the `<?` or `?>` for anything that goes there. Another approach would be to create an intent called "done", give it the single training example of "done", and then use `#done` as your node's condition.

Comment: Nope not a dialog node. I want sys-person to recognize more names than it was trained on. Like non-english names and names of companies like A.B.C Corp.  For instance if person name is brown , If I ask what is the bank balance of brown?

Comment: @JohnRuby Gotcha. I wish there was a way to extend the system entities, but since there isn't, we just need to find other ways to accomplish the same goals. In your case, I do still think that contextual entities are the ideal solution for your use case. You could set up an intent with examples like "What's the bank balance of brown" and "What is brown's bank balance" and other such examples, annotating "brown" as a `@name` entity, and then you can work with that in your dialog nodes from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi John
Don't wish to dismiss your entity pattern, however from experience I have seen its almost impossible to determine a complete list of people names. I use both @sys-person and my own @names entity which contains over 6,000 common names, and we are still adding missing values to the list. We also have a @bad_names list which contains names that match common words like; summer, cherry, star, cj, etc.
 By using both your intent or @sys-person or @names, etc in your condition you have a good chance to catch a high percent of the users messages.